# Adding dozens of images to lightSlider via jquery has off results

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to lightSlider, and not good at JS, it's been years since I've used it, and it's starting to come back to me slowly.   Now I remember why I wanted to work on the back-end and not the UI.

So, I am using lightSlider, and we have the basics, and in the HTML code we have this:

Now, in the javascript code we have a loop which gets images like this:

```
$.each(that.selectedSeries.instance, function (index, instance) {

     var url = get url for this image

    $("#instances").append($('<li data-thumb="' + url >
       <img src="' + theUrl + '" alt="Lights" class="thumbnailimage"/></li>'));
```

So, we may be loading dozens, maybe even hundreds of images and adding them one at a time to the DOM.  The 'li' tags get added as the example shows, but what happens is that the thumbnail images load and load, and it wraps around the screen taking up all available screen space.   Then it stops.   If I resize the screen, then the slider re-adjusts, and I get the scolling thumbnails.

I tried to refresh the slider after all the images have been loaded, but that did not help.   I tried to hide and show the slider after the images have been loaded, but that didn't help either.

The original developer had a basic slider that worked perfectly, and the only reason we chose to go with a new slider is because we wanted images lazy-loaded.   I tried looking for a bunch of sliders that would have this coded already.   We don't have time to code a solution ourselves, so if we could find a good slider that would be great.  if we could make lightSlider work better, we would ....

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked out [Slick Slider](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)? I personally have had good experiences with it and it supports lazy loading.

Comment: I haven't checked it out yet, but I certainly will ... thanks for the suggestion.   I will let you know how it works out.